# Jasmine pass in broswer, fail in grunt-contrib-jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, phantomjs, gruntjs

I've created some jasmine test for my Plugin.

They all pass in the browser (chrome) but for some reason, when i use "grunt-contrib-jasmine" task in my terminal, most of them fail.

Here an example:

```js
it("scroll to the correct floor", function() {

  // return and instance of my plugin (ascensor)
  var ascensor = getInstanceOfAscensor({});
  var floorArray;

  // Triggered when 'next' is triggered
  ascensor.on("scrollStart", function(event, floor) {
    // floor look like {from:0, to:1}
    floorArray = floor;
  });

  // trigger an 'next' event which
  // trigger a 'scrollStart' 
  // event inside the plugin
  ascensor.trigger("next");

  // Spec
  expect(floorArray.from).toBe(0);
  expect(floorArray.to).toBe(1);
});


Terminal Output:
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'floorArray.from')
```

The complete test:
https://github.com/kirkas/Ascensor.js/blob/master/test/spec/optionsSpec.js

Comment: Apprently the `scrollStart` event is not triggered. Can you just post the relevant code that is supposed to trigger it from the `next` trigger? FYI, I opened an issue on github that I encountered while randomy having a look at your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for you note, but the problem is that the test pass in browser (event is triggered), but not in phantomJS, and i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem, i was using the `loadFixtures` function from jasmine-jquery, which refer to a relative path (`"spec/javascripts/fixtures"`).

The solution was to put this line at the top of my test, which refer to the fixture folder.

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'path/to/your/fixture';
```